# gpg: invalid auto-key-locate list

Tags: tor-install

I'm attempting to install Tor, but I can't get the signing key to verify the download.

```
$ gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org
gpg: invalid auto-key-locate list
gpg: Invalid option "--locate-keys"
```

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of the `gpg` command available in Ubuntu 16.04, in separate packages:

- `gnupg`, which is GnuPG version 1.4.20; and
- `gnupg2`, which is GnuPG version 2.1.11.

The `--locate-keys` option was added in 2.0.10, as was the `nodefault` value for `--auto-key-locate`.  Given that you're unable to use the `--locate-keys` option, I strongly suspect that the version of GnuPG you're running is version 1.4.20.

To run the newer version of GnuPG on an Ubuntu 16.04 system, you need to install the `gnupg2` package, and use the `gpg2` command rather than `gpg`.

However, WKD support was added [in GnuPG 2.1.12](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/commit/87de9e19edf0311ca0342e15ef44ebe40e32861e), which means that even using `gpg2` you won't be able to run the command given on the Tor project webpage.  However...

The WKD protocol is a public one, and via the magic of [tutorials like this one](https://keyserver.mattrude.com/guides/web-key-directory/) I've figured out that the key you need can be downloaded via HTTPS.  Thus, the complete command you can use (which should, I *think*, work even in GnuPG 1.4.20) looks like this:

```
wget -O - https://openpgpkey.torproject.org/.well-known/openpgpkey/hu/kounek7zrdx745qydx6p59t9mqjpuhdf | gpg --import
```

Comment: Both gnupg & gnupg2 were installed, showing the versions you listed.  I removed gnupg and the original command now gives a message saying I need to install gnupg.  The dpkg command shows `un  gnupg          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  gnupg-agent    2.1.11-6ubun amd64        GNU privacy guard - cryptographic
un  gnupg-doc      <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  gnupg2         2.1.11-6ubun amd64        GNU privacy guard - a free PGP re`

Comment: What "original command" are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to `$ gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org`.

Comment: You ran `gpg` and it told you to install `gnupg`?  I have never seen anything even vaguely like that.  Unless, perhaps, it's Ubuntu's "command not found" handler getting in the way; try running `hash -r`, or starting a new shell.  That might fix it.  The exact error message, rather than an interpretation of it, may otherwise be helpful.

Comment: Here's the command and response:
`$ gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org
The program 'gpg' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install gnupg
`
I ran a `hash -r`. It completed without printing anything to the console.

Comment: Righto, so it *was* Ubuntu's "command not found" handler getting in the way.  That `hash -r` didn't produce any output is expected (if that's what you meant), it isn't supposed to.  You should be able to re-run the original `gpg` command now.  That should print out the key(s) it found, even if you already had them in your local keyring, or an error message if it couldn't find any key with the specified ID.

Comment: I rebooted, opened a shell and ran the gpg command.  It gave me `$ gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org
The program 'gpg' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install gnupg`.  Was I supposed to do something else first?

Comment: Oh, good grief, Ubuntu's `gnupg2` package doesn't appear to use alternatives.  You'll have to use `gpg2` instead of `gpg` as the command to run.

Comment: One of the original messages is gone, but I'm afraid it still won't work.  `gpg2 --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org
gpg: invalid auto-key-locate list`  Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: Turns out Ubuntu 16.04's version of `gnupg2` doesn't support WKD.  I've edited my answer to provide another option.

Comment: That did the trick.  I proceeded with the TOR instructions, saved the key to a file and successfully verified the signature.  Thank you

Comment: @womble Can you please contact the person in charge of the [How can I verify Tor Browser's signature? | Tor Project | Support](https://support.torproject.org/tbb/how-to-verify-signature/) and tell him/her to precise in their doc that `gnupg2 version >= 2.1.12` is needed ?

Comment: I'm sure you've got just as much ability to do that as I have.